# JavaScript: how to convert this utc date time string to local time

Tags: javascript

I have a UTC date string like this `"2013-08-22T00:35:00"`, how do I use Javascript to convert it to a local computer time? so after conversion the time should be `2013-08-21 20:35`

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
new Date("2013-08-22T00:35:00")
```

work for you?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Or just use libraries designed for that, like [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
moment("2013-08-22T00:35:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript convert datetime string to local on creating new instance.

```
var date = new Date("2013-08-22T00:35:00");
date.toString() //local date
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8moj78n8/)